# Solidify modifier causing strange artefacting?

Tags: modeling

I have made the following part of a model which I want to add some thickness to.

[image]

When I add a solidify modifier to the model I get these strange artifacts:

[image]

I tried to merge vertices by distance to check for any duplicate geometry to rule out Z fighting, but there isn't any:

[image]

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Solidify causing this.

I expect that 0.1 thickness is too small for this object, so increase thickness value.

You may expect, that 0.1 thickness must be a big value, but this value multiplies with object scale, so you may apply scale to fix that (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> Scale)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. With a larger thickness the artifacts are still there. I tried applying rotation and scale too, but this also didn't help. Thanks for the suggestion though.